# Can't get openssl upgraded

Tags: python3, openssl

I have Ubuntu 14.06 LTS. I need to use python 3.6.5 with openssl 1.1.0. The openssl verison I have is: `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`

I tried to upgrade openssl using: `$ sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade openssl`. After that I checked the verison. But nothing gotr upgraded. Can you please tell me how to upgrade openssl to the version 1.1.0? 
And how to link the new version openssl 1.1.1 with my python 3.6.5 which I can run only by navigating to the following directory `/usr/local/bin` (i.e. I can not get python3 by typing the command python. If I type python I get python 2.7). Please help me.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (released 2014.April; there was no June release) supports the version then available, 1.01 (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openssl) with security fixes backported to that version (*newer versions with newer features exist in later versions of Ubuntu, only security fixes are backported*). The version 1.1.0 is available for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Python 2.7 was the default in 14.04, you should be able to use python3 to run Python 3.4  (*if not check your $PATH*)

Comment: What do you mean? I should download Ubuntu 18? is it possible to have openssl 1.1.0 in Ubuntu 14?

Comment: You can of course load it from source, https://forums.servethehome.com/index.php?resources/installing-openssl-1-1-0-on-ubuntu.21/ is a blog telling you how found using startpage.com.